# Looking for an element (in i position) in one list and returning a element (in the same i position) of another list

Tags: list

what I have is:

```
present_tense = ["say","make","go",'take','come','see',"know", "get", "give", "find", "think", "tell", "become", "feel", "leave"]
past_tense = ["said","made",...]
```

And I want the program searches if the word introduced in a raw_input is in `present_tense` and if so, it retrieves the element in the `past_tense` list placed in the same position.

At the moment this is what I have, but I suppose there is a neat way.

```
def pasttense(verb):
    if verb in present_tense [0]:           
      pastform = "said"
    elif verb in present_tense [1]:
      pastform = "made"
    elif verb in present_tense [2]:
      pastform = "went"
    elif verb in present_tense [3]:
      pastform = "took"
```

Comment: see about [ForLoop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) if you say about **python**

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
pastform = past_tense[present_tense.index(verb)]
```

but if `verb` not in `present_tense` then raise exception

so if exception not expected you can check that `verb` in `present_tense`

```
if verb in present_tense:
    pastform = past_tense[present_tense.index(verb)]
```